# Firebase : How to secure content sent without login?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm building a hybrid mobile app with Firebase as my backend. I want to let users post on a wall any message they want without authentication, but I feel concerned about spam possibilities. I mean, if users don't have to be authenticated to be able to post, my security rules are basically empty and anyone who gets the endpoint can post an infinite amount of content. And I don't see what I could do against it.

So I know about [anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), but I'm not sure if it really fix the issue. The endpoint remains open, after all, just behind the necessity to call a method before. It adds a little complexity but not much, I think.

What I wonder is if there is a possibility to check for the call origin, to make sure it comes from my app and nothing else. Or, if you have another idea to get this more secure, I'm open to everything. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps explore the possibility of adding Captcha?

Comment: The `initializeApp` credentials are client-side and anyone with those will be able to write data to open locations in the database. You cannot control that without auth. However, you could control what could be written to those locations with `.validate` and `.write` rules. That is, you could use a `.write` rule that allows only inserts and a `.validate` rule that limits data to particular values of a particular size, etc.

Comment: You can optionally put the limit for anonymous users on the day of publication. Let's limit of 10 posts a day.

This will motivate the user to register if they want to extend the limit on the number of posts.

Captcha is also a great option

Comment: @DebanjanDhar yes, Captcha could be an option... But no one likes those, even more on mobile !

Comment: @cartant this can help I guess, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a combination of [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) on the client, and firebase [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) on the backend.

You send the message you want to add to the store along with the captcha to the cloud function. In the cloud function, we first verify the captcha. If this one is ok, we add the message to the store. This works, because when adding items to the store via a cloud function, firebase authentication rules are ignored.

Here's an example cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const rp = require('request-promise')
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true,
});

admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {
  cors(req, res, () => {

    // the body is a json of form {message: Message, captcha: string}
    const body = req.body;

    // here we verify whether the captcha is ok. We need a remote server for 
    // for this so you might need a paid plan
    rp({
        uri: 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        method: 'POST',
        formData: {
            secret: '<SECRET>',
            response: body.captcha
        },
        json: true
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.success) {
            // the captcha is ok! we can now send the message to the store
            admin.firestore()
                .collection('messages')
                .add(body.message)
                .then(writeResult => {
                    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
                });
        } else {
            res.send({success: false, msg: "Recaptcha verification failed."})
        }
    }).catch(reason => {
        res.send({success: false, msg: "Recaptcha request failed."})
    })
  });
})
```

And here's some more info: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/guard-your-web-content-from-abuse-with.html